# Why can't I 'fetch' some URLs from my Capacitor app on Android?

Tags: android, fetch, pouchdb, capacitor

I'm trying to write a mobile app via Capacitor that makes use of PouchDB.  When I run the app in the emulator via Android Studio the connection to the remote CouchDB instance fails.  I've tracked this down to a failure in the `fetch` API for certain URLs when running on Android.

To debug I made a minimal web application and wrapped it using Capacitor to run on Android.  The app includes the following code

```js
const testFetch = (url) => {
    console.log("Testing fetch", url)
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((t) => {
            console.log("Respose from fetch:", url)
            console.log(t)
            console.log("that was it")
        })
        .catch((reason) => {
            console.log("FETCH FAILED", url, reason)
        })
}
```

I then have three tests:

```js
  testFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");   // just some JSON 
  testFetch("http://10.0.2.2:5984/simple");    // local pouchdb instance 
  testFetch("http://10.0.2.2:8080/sample.json");  // local http server + CORS
```

The second two use the IP address that is an alias for the development machine when running in the Android emulator.  I confirmed that I can access all of these URLs from the browser on the emulator but the app succeeds on the first and fails on the second two (error: `TypeError: Failed to fetch`).  When running the base web app in the browser, all succeed (with localhost instead of 10.0.2.2).

CORS headers are in place on all URLs.  As far as I can see the app doesn't even try to access the two servers that fail - no HEAD requests for example.  I've also tried various other URLs and can't see a pattern to the failures -- eg. it's not the port number != 80.

Any clues as to what is going on would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the HTTP response status code?

Comment: There is no status code, just a 'Failed to fetch' error.  The failed calls don't send out a request as far as I can see (nothing logged in the local http server or pouchdb).  If there is any way for me to dive deeper into what fetch is doing that would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the thing I didn't notice that the failing URLs had in common was http rather than https. It turns out that `fetch` silently fails to work for any http URL, just giving the error 'Failed to fetch'.

I'm not sure whether this is a feature of the Android web view or of Capacitor itself.  The Capacitor docs suggest that [using `https` is a good idea](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/security#network-security) but not that `http` won't work.

This policy doesn't get altered by setting a Content Security Policy in the main page header.

The original goal was to connect a local PouchDB database to a remote CouchDB instance.  This now works as long as the CouchDB instance is served via `https`.   Without that you just get silent failure to sync.

Comment: I suffer from same problem. My CouchDB database served using `https://`but got same silent `Type Error: Failed to fetch`. Is there any solution?

Comment: I don't know where the restriction is being implemented.  The Android web view doesn't seem to have this restriction so I'm guessing it's implemented by Capacitor. I've not had time to dig further into that.

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same problem who find themselves here (using Ionic, Capacitor, Android etc). I managed to get this (connecting to a remote CouchDB server via http) working by doing two things:

Add:

```
android: { allowMixedContent: true }
```

to capacitor.config.ts

and add:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to  in AndroidManifest.xml

(Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/979/)